# postgres regex to find chars \u0001 to \u0031

Tags: regex, postgresql

How do I find the all white space characters like \u0004 or \u0001 in postgres column values?
It can be in the beginning, in the middle or in the end. I don't want to get space (\u0032) values too just white space characters from \u0001 to \u0031 included.

Something like below, but it's not correct it selects the spaces too???

```
select column where column ~* '[\u0001-\u0031]'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably confusing [`\uwxyz`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CHARACTER-ENTRY-ESCAPES-TABLE) format with decimal base. Check Unicode's [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) chart to be sure. I guess that you want C0 controls range from U+0001 to U+001F, so you could write:

```
SELECT  E'\u0033 dfgdgdg' ~ E'[\\u0001-\\u001F]' AS isMatch;
```

or using octal base `\xyz`:

```
SELECT  E'\u0033 dfgdgdg' ~ E'[\\001-\\037]' AS isMatch;
```

Another handy way is to write pattern with [dollar quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) (so you don't need to additionally escape backslashes):

```
$$[\u0001-\u001F]$$
$$[\x001-\x01f]$$
$$[\001-\037]$$
```

Comment: For completeness U+0000-U+FFFF are defined as (BMP) **code points** (written as hexadecimal number).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match any whitespace character except normal space, then you can use this regex:

```
[^\S ]
```

Answer (score 0):

One White space character is 0x20 and not 0x31. The range of unicode characters below the whitespace wouldbe `\u0001` to `\u0019`

Comment: This returns true
select '\u0033 dfgdgdg' ~* '[\u0001-\u0031]'  as isMatch;
so I know my query is bad

Comment: @Hyperboreus You are not correct about the terms: **0x20** is not the only white space character. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character